# how to make a conditional if statement so that yahoo email have different header

Tags: php, email

I just want to have two different `header` in my form. all visitors have yahoo mail must have different `header` from other email.

**i try this but unfortunately its not working**

```
if($visitor_email == "@yahoo.com"){

// display something here

                      } else {

                $headers = "From: $visitor_email \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

                              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($visitor_email, "@yahoo.com")!=false){

    // display something here

} else {
    $headers = "From: $visitor_email \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
}
```

That will recognize any yahoo email, even if it ends with `@yahoo.com.br`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions

$visitor_email has to match a pattern *@yahoo.com and not be equal to yahoo.com

Refer [PHP - Perform a regular expression match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)